# Can I get someone to reopen my Area 51 Proposal?

Tags: discussion, area-51, vote-to-reopen

I am attempting to create a new [3D Graphics SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/55139/3d-graphics) because the previous one went defunct. My proposal was closed because they said it was a duplicate of Graphic Design. This is *not* the case because 3D questions pertaining to Maya, 3DS Max, etc. are [considered *off topic* on that site](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/554/do-we-still-feel-like-3d-questions-are-out-of-scope-here).

I really would like to be able to ask Maya questions on a Stack Exchange platform.

Comment: You already asked this in the appropriate location: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/10448/please-re-open-this-is-not-a-duplicate-3d-discussions-are-off-topic-in-graphic Why ask it again here?

Comment: And where it concerns the Meta discussion you link, the accepted and positively scored answers states *"As far as I'm concerned, 3D is in. Graphic design includes 3D."*. Perhaps it's worth bringing more attention to that subject to get a decision.

Comment: I voted to close this as off-topic. The Area51 part is best asked on Area51 I'd say. And as for the GD SE, part of your question might be best addressed in their Meta.

Comment: Ok, sorry if this is off topic here. Just distressed because there seem to be conflicting answers to this topic. I didn't realize that the discussion zone was the 'Meta' of Area51

Comment: Proposal has been re-opened. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Why are you asking here?

Comment: @Xarcell - I must have mis-read the Area51 FAQ. I saw the link for Additional questions that lead to here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Historically, 3D was banned from Graphic Design, for reasons I no longer remember. But, the latest consensus is that 3D is acceptable. I have just added that to the FAQ over at GD. Welcome to Graphic Design!

Comment: Thank you @PearsonArtPhoto! I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

The very question you linked off Graphic Design's meta allows the questions of 3D graphic questions.

Doesn't seem like your request has much merit. Ask your question on Graphic Design.

Comment: The FAQ of the site is unclear on the issue however. It seems to exclude 3D as a topic, apparent Meta consensus notwithstanding: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq This does not seem to be a settled issue.

Comment: @Bart: Well then, it's an issue with the site though, I'll notify that site's moderators and see what they can do about it. But it seems as if the natural consensus (of at least 2 moderators) is that 3D design is *allowed*.